# Invoke a function on tool mode script reload

Tags: godot

How do I invoke a function every time the Script is loaded or reloaded?

```
tool

func _reload():
    print("Changes have been made and saved! Script has been reloaded")

func _load():
    print("Project was just opened! Script has been loaded")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by reloaded (or why it is an issue), but it probably is one of these:

- When you add a `Node` to the scene tree (or when you enable a plugin, which is adding the `EditorPlugin` to scene tree of the editor), or when it is loaded (all plugins are loaded when you load the project), the code in `_enter_tree` will run. Similarly when it is removed (or when the plugin is disabled), the code in `_exit_tree` will run. *Be aware that for `tool` scripts that you run manually (`EditorScript`), these don't work. So make a `Node` (or an `EditorPlugin`).*
- There is a signal that will notify when the script of an object changed. It is appropriately named `"script_changed"`. So if you want to handle the situation when the tool script was modified, and thus reloaded, you could connect to that signal. You may also want to take advantage of the of `_init`, which is the first virtual method that Godot calls (on `Node`s you can also use `_enter_tree` and `_ready`). *The signal `"script_changed"` is emitted before `_init` is called in the new script.*
- If you want to handle when properties of a `Node` are modified (I'm including this since you mention "changed has been made"), you would have to use setters (with `setget`), or you could intercept the properties in `_set`.

Since you mention "Project was just opened", I think you want to make an `EditorPlugin`, and then you can use `_enter_tree` and `_exit_tree`.

I haven't found a way to get a notification when the currently edited scene on the editor is saved. However, saving the scene does not mean `tool` script are loaded or reloaded in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible with GDScript, but since the question doesn't specify a language, I've found the following to work in C# in Godot 4.1:

```cs
[Tool]
public partial class MyScript : Node, ISerializationListener
{
    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        GD.Print("Script has been reloaded");
    }
}
```

The `ISerializationListener` interface is specific to the .NET build of Godot though.